# Split a polygon 56% west, 44% east

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, splitting

Using ArcMap 10.6 with the Basic license, I need to split our district boundary into two sections. The west side needs to be 56% of the area, while the east side is 44% of the area. Also, our district has exclaves inside that are not part of the district boundary polygon. I believe there would be a tool for this task but I am unsure of what it may be.

Comment: It's unlikely there would be a tool for this, but you could certainly write some ArcPy to do this in under 30 lines of code. You merely need to use a binary search algorithm, starting at the midpoint between east and west, moving the line half the distance between the previous guesses until the area is within a threshold of ideal (perfectly 56% might not be possible, but 55.999-56.001 probably is; if the percentage stops changing, you've exceeded the precision of the data, and will have to quit there).

Comment: I have no experience with ArcPy. Perhaps now is the time to learn.

Comment: I had a similar problem once but I needed to split the polygons from north to south.  I made an ASCII version of the polygon, then used Python to step through each cell in the ascii file until the percentages were satisfied.  The code skips NoData so it would work for your exclaves.  I suppose you could rotate your polygon and run the tool as is.  Let me know if you are interested in the code and I will post it to GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Python is good idea. So for a table structure like that:

[image]

below script will modify original shape(s) by one with area equal to defined percentage of original. So work on backup copy !!!.

```py
import arcpy
polygons = "POLYGONS"
tolerance = 1

def splitMe (shp,leftSide):
    E = shp.extent
    low, high = E.XMin,E.XMax
    pLow,pHigh = E.lowerLeft,E.upperLeft
    pLow.Y, pHigh.Y = E.YMin,E.YMax
    totalArea = shp.area
    while high - low > tolerance:
        mid = (low+high)/2
        pLow.X,pHigh.X = mid,mid
        cutLine = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([pLow,pHigh]), SR)
        try:
            leftPgon = shp.cut(cutLine)[0]
            if leftPgon.area < totalArea*leftSide/100:low=mid
            else: high = mid
        except: low -= tolerance
    return leftPgon

SR = arcpy.Describe(polygons).spatialReference
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(polygons,("Shape@", "LEFT_PERC")) as cursor:
    for shp,percent in cursor:
        LP = splitMe(shp,percent)
        cursor.updateRow((LP,percent))
        arcpy.AddMessage(LP.area/shp.area*100)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

It takes few second to split kilometres wide shape by line no more than 1 m away (see tolerance in a script) from 'true' split line. Script using [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to find solution and
quits search when **difference between search limits drops** below tolerance, so change tolerance to 0.001 m if you want. It will take slightly longer to complete.

Try to understand logic, good for Python learner. Script itself can be significantly reduced, but ArcMap performance with geometries is next to nothing, so one should use silly tricks like *try* and *except* to cheat it into work(: 
In example shown it failed originally with polygon at the West (ideology?).