# Splitting polygon into equal area polygons using shapely

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, splitting, equal-area

I would like to split complex geometries into `n` smallest geometries of the same area in Python. While I can divide simple geometry in the following way:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiPolygon, Polygon
from shapely.ops import split

def splitPolygon(polygon, nx, ny):
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = polygon.bounds
    dx = (maxx - minx) / nx
    dy = (maxy - miny) / ny

    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = polygon.bounds
    dx = (maxx - minx) / nx  # width of a small part
    dy = (maxy - miny) / ny  # height of a small part
    horizontal_splitters = [LineString([(minx, miny + i*dy), (maxx, miny + i*dy)]) for i in range(ny)]
    vertical_splitters = [LineString([(minx + i*dx, miny), (minx + i*dx, maxy)]) for i in range(nx)]
    splitters = horizontal_splitters + vertical_splitters
    result = polygon
    
    for splitter in splitters:
        result = MultiPolygon(split(result, splitter))
    
    return result
```

I am not able to find a way to do the same for complex geometries.

Is there any similar plugin or function in Python like [Splitting polygon into equal area polygons in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321021)?

A geometry could be the following one that can be dowloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12PuDwThYLN3T5VfvXphEPElv8ewGJjL_?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Equal-area partitioning of irregular features can be *extremely* computationally intensive, and if they are highly irregular, then they can be NP Hard or NP Complete.

Comment: I developed an algorithm by using PyQGIS. It considers cut angle and proportion of involved areas. For instance, I used your irregular geometry for dividing it with a cut angle of 45 º in two parts and 30/70 proportion. Result was as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctbUx.png

Comment: Very simple algorithm if shapely has split function that works on multipart polygon https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364262/split-a-polygon-56-west-44-east/364480#364480